# tcpdump --- capture packets to a non-rotating file

Tags: tcpdump

```
tcpdump -i eth0 -C 5 -W 1 -w <file name>&
```

I use the command above to capture packets to a 5MB pcap file on an Ubuntu machine. Once the pcap file reaches the maximum size (5MB), the file gets rotated and starts again from 0KB.

I need to know whether we can stop the tcpdump from rotating the file once it reaches its max size and drop the packets from then.

Comment: You can limit the number of packets captured and the seconds, I think. No ideia how to make it stop after capturing n bytes.

Comment: From the man page section on `-W` option: "Used in conjunction with the -G option,  this  will  limit  the  number  of rotated  dump  files  that get created, exiting with status 0 when reaching the limit."  I've never used this option, but looks like a potential basis for an answer.

Comment: @user4556274 I was also reading it, and it is a bit obscure. Feel free to add an answer if you are confy with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way!!!!

We can do a hack in `tcpdump` as below

```
tcpdump -i eth0 -C 5 -W 2 -w my.pcap -z ./stop.sh&
```

`stop.sh`

```
# !/bin/sh
pkill tcpdump
rm my.pcap0
```

and it worked for me......

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to wireshark/tshark:

```
tshark -i eth0 -a filesize:5000 -w my.pcap &
```

Comment: No i dont have access..:(

Answer (score 0):

looks like tcpdump (4.9.2) only honors file count (-W) when used together with capture time (-G).
the other way to capture to only one file is by limit packet count (-c).
tcpdump seems not be able to write to a non-rotating file limited by size (-C).

according to source code there is this exit statement

```c
if (Cflag == 0 && Wflag > 0 && Gflag_count >= Wflag) {
    (void)fprintf(stderr, "Maximum file limit reached: %d\n",
        Wflag);
    info(1);
    exit_tcpdump(0);
    /* NOTREACHED */
}
```

which tests especially Cflag (file size) to be zero.

example 1: by packet count

```
# tcpdump -vi any -w ./count.pcap -c 42 ip
```

example 2: by capture time

```
# tcpdump -vi any -w ./time.pcap -G 7 -W 1 ip
```

result: 1 file each

```
# ls
count.pcap  time.pcap
```

HTH